# Import/Export XML data into SQL Server Compact Edition?

Tags: xml, database, import, export, sql-server-ce

Does it exist a Microsoft tool or a sql query for import/export XML data into SQL Server Compact Edition ?

Like this for SQL Server : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191184.aspx#binary_byte_stream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have received an answer from a Microsoft Senior Program Manager :

*One option to use is the SQL Server Integration Studio that installs with SQL Server 2008 or SQL Server 2008 R2. Please see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140269.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140269(v=SQL.90).aspx for more information*